# Do I need a residence permit card to travel to other Schengen countries?

Tags: schengen, norway, long-stay-visas

I have been granted a skilled worker permit in Norway. I got an entry visa (type D visa) to enter Norway. It is a single entry one. Is it possible for me to travel to other Schengen countries (i.e. Switzerland) before getting the residence permit card?

Comment: YOur visa is fine for travel to other Schengen countries; the long answer is wrong

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, as long as the D-visa is valid, you can travel to other Schengen countries.

Since it is a single entry visa, you are however not allowed to leave and reenter the Schengen are, but must stay within.

Comment: @Sahan To clarify, it means you cannot leave Schengen until getting your residence permit card

Answer (score -3):

Only if your visa is really a schengen visa ( not national level ) AND it is schengen USV ( Uniform Schengen Visa ) and not LTV ( Limited territorial validity ).

You should be able to check on your visa if there are any restrictions specifically written on it and what type it is .

If the `valid for' field says something like`etats schengen`(french ) or`schengen states`(english) or`schengenstaten` (german) or any otheer language variant and nothing else then it should be a USV. the

If the field has something like a state name, or state code, or multiple entries ( for example `D-EE-P`, or `-ES` or `D-P-F-I-LT` ) or any other remark / restriction - you should check the individual exception .

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer.  Nothing is specifically written on my visa. How can I know whether it is USV or LTV?

Comment: If no special restriction or allowance in the valid for field or other remarks  ( for example the likes of  `valid only for Country X` or `not valid for country Y ` ). also see my edit.

Comment: @ObmerkKronen This answer is incorrect. D visas nowadays only list the state it was issued by, but are valid for Schengen-wide travel

Comment: D visas are *always* valid for the entire Schengen area. Only C visas can be issued with a limited territorial validity (LTV).